# XCode 7.3 ScrollViews and Navigation Controllers

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, xcode7

I have been bashing my head at trying to solve this, what will probably be a small, issue involving a UIScrollView. A little background might help.

I have a ViewController, which has a Navigation Bar. At the top right, there is a button ('Add' style) which does a Push to this new view controller, named Add Bill.

On Add Bill, I have unchecked "Adjust Scroll View Insets", and set the size to "Freeform". I added a NavigationItem, called Add Bill, with no back button, but with a BarButtonItem, Cancel, which is on the Left

I then added a new UIScrollView, and with auto constraints, unchecked "Constrain to Margins" and set all relational constraints to zero.

Within the UIScrollView, I added a UIView, and with auto constraints, set all relational constraints to zero, and called it ContentView.

I then Linked (control click) *from* ContentView *to* View (the UIScrollView's parent) and set constraints for "Equal Widths" and "Equal Heights", and set the "Equal Heights" priority to "Low".

Now I add items into ContentView just like any other view, but when simulated, or installed on my phone, it does either of the following

- Gives me no scroll capabilities
- Gives me minimal scroll capabilities, ie it scrolls, but only about 40 pixels worth

Here's an image of my Scene Explorer

[image]

If you have any idea about going about this, or where I am messing up, please let me know! Thanks, and cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link may help you. I was also in this situation few days before. This link helped me very much other than other links.

[Enable scrolling to View to allow multiple elements](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/769676/Enable-scrolling-to-View-to-allow-multiple-element)